# Is this hard disk dead? Is there a way to get it to power on?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have dismounted hard disk from notebook because the system were not loading and there were no bootable options in BIOS so I decided to put this hard disk to my desktop PC, however the hard disk is connected well but it does not turn on (I mean it is not starting to shake when I turn on my PC like all hard disks).

Also I cannot see this hard disk in hardware list. Does that mean that the hard disk has definitely gone? Is there any chance to recover data or how to turn on the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience hard disk failures fall into 2 categories - a dead circuit board or dead mechanics. If the drive is not powering up at all - no lights or noises or hums - I would guess at circuit board or component failure.

If you have electronic engineering knowledge you can diagnose the board and replace the failed component(s).

Otherwise find a working hard disk which shares the make and model and swap out the circuit boards in an attempt to get the disk working and data copied off.

Comment: … or just get the data off your backup & bin the offender - whole lot easier ;)